# Wait until the webpage loads in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, timedelay, time-wait

I am using scrapy script to load URL using "yield".

```
MyUrl = "www.example.com"
request = Request(MyUrl, callback=self.mydetail)
yield request
def mydetail(self, response):
    item['Description'] = response.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//text()").extract()
    return item
```

The URL seems to take minimum 5 seconds to load. So I want Scrapy to wait for some time to load the entire text in item['Description'].
I tried "DOWNLOAD_DELAY" in settings.py but no use.

Comment: Scrapy downloads the whole response before running your callback. That load time you notice on your browser may be additional things fetched/rendered via javascript which scrapy does not do on it's own. Try doing `scrapy shell <url>` to see that scrapy "sees" on the site. You need to check what else the page fetches and modify your code to match that or use a headless browser to render the page's javascript. (e.g. Splash, Selenium)

Comment: I have used splash for rendering javascript. But the output is empty. I am not sure whether scrapy is rendering my javascript page

Comment: Regardless of if you use splash, what @marven said holds true, Scrapy will wait for the whole response before proceeding.  If you use Splash, than Splash becomes the new "webserver". From Scrapy's point-of-view, Splash is it's endpoint and will wait until Splash returns the entirety of the response.

Comment: As is, you're callback is "self.mydetail", but the function is "jobdetail".  Is this a typo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a brief view on firebug or another tool to capture responses for Ajax requests, which were made by javascript code. You are able to make a chain of responses to catch those ajax requests which appear after uploading of the page.There are several related questions: [parse ajax content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706111/scrapy-crawlspider-for-ajax-content),
[retreive final page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139602/parsing-ajax-responses-to-retrieve-final-url-content-in-scrapy),
[parse dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax).